# how to update nested dictionary types in python

Tags: python

I am really a beginner in Python and I wanted to update a nested dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
players_score= {}

per_round_score = dict()
name =["ram","shyam"]
for k in range(0,len(name)):
    for _ in range(0,2):
        per_round_score[f'round_{k}'] = {k:name[k]}
    players_score.update(per_round_score)
print(players_score)
```

Output of the code is:

`{'round_0': {0: 'ram'}, 'round_1': {1: 'shyam'}}`

But I want output as:

`{'round_0': {"ram":0 ,"shyam":0}, 'round_1': {"ram":1,'shyam':1}}`

Comment: `{0: 'ram',0:"shyam"}` this is not a valid dictionary

Comment: sorry i updated required op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip()` function returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together, and then the second item in each passed iterator is paired together etc.

You can try this:

```
players_score = {}

per_round_score = dict()
name = ["ram", "shyam"]
for k in range(0, len(name)):
    per_round_score["round_" + str(k)] = dict(zip(name, [k for i in range(0, len(name))])))
    players_score.update(per_round_score)

print(players_score)
```

Output:

```
{'round_0': {'ram': 0, 'shyam': 0}, 'round_1': {'ram': 1, 'shyam': 1}}
```

Comment: This will break if `name` list contains more than 2 values